# how to take mean of a subset of a dataframe within for loop in r

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset of 203614 rows and 3 columns with names "price","Timestamp",energy. whereas timestamp has repitions for every transaction

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctYjF.jpg)

price is in numeric

timestamp is in posixct

energy in numeric

```
dput(head(dataset))

structure(list(Price = c(18, 20, 23, 15, 15, 15), Timestamp.Transaction = structure(c(1388500200, 1388500200, 1388502000, 1388502000, 1388502000, 1388502000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Energy = c(414, 230, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("Price", "Timestamp.Transaction", "Energy"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have to do these following steps by  applying loops

1) i have to subset the dataset with "timestamp" difference of 1.33days from certain timestamp

2) caluclate the min, max, avg of the price in subset and assign it to new dataframe

3)i have to iterate above steps for every 15min duration

NOTE: m1 is my dataset

t1 is the timestamp vector as it has repeated values i took only unique values out of it

```
t1 <- unique(timestamp)
```

i have tried this but it is taking to much time compile and the reults are wrong

```
    for(i in 125:length(t1)){    for(j in 1:203614){    s1[j,] <- subset(m1,(m1$Timestamp.Transaction <=t1[i] & m1$Timestamp.Transaction >= t1[i]-115200 )   }}
```

Comment: hi i have added a picture of dataset. please check it

Comment: structure(list(Price = c(18, 20, 23, 15, 15, 15), Timestamp.Transaction = structure(c(1388500200, 
1388500200, 1388502000, 1388502000, 1388502000, 1388502000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Energy = c(414, 230, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("Price", 
"Timestamp.Transaction", "Energy"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Did you try my solution? Considering the size of your data, I believe going with a vectorized approach might save you some compution time.

Comment: i have tried it. i got subsetting and it fast. i am trying now to caluclate mean, max, average and weekday, day of the year  and allocate it to new dataframe

Comment: how can i format the summary values and new values that i find in the format as.  mean,min,max,wday,yday as column names of a datframe and their values into its respective columns

Comment: Hm, this needs some reformatting. I will look into it, but it's gonna be a few hours before I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your subsets in a list with

```
newdf <- lapply(t1, function(x) 
  subset(dataset, dataset$Timestamp.Transaction <=x & dataset$Timestamp.Transaction >= x-115200))
```

and then get a list of the `summary()` of the `Price`-columns of all your subsets with

```
summaries <- lapply(newdf, function(x) summary(x["Price"]))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
     Price     
 Min.   :18.0  
 1st Qu.:18.5  
 Median :19.0  
 Mean   :19.0  
 3rd Qu.:19.5  
 Max.   :20.0  

[[2]]
     Price      
 Min.   :15.00  
 1st Qu.:15.00  
 Median :16.50  
 Mean   :17.67  
 3rd Qu.:19.50  
 Max.   :23.00
```

To name the summary entries, just use

```
names(summaries) <- sapply(t1, function(x) paste(x-115200, x, sep = " - "))
```

New Output:

```
$`2013-12-30 07:30:00 - 2013-12-31 15:30:00`
     Price     
 Min.   :18.0  
 1st Qu.:18.5  
 Median :19.0  
 Mean   :19.0  
 3rd Qu.:19.5  
 Max.   :20.0  

$`2013-12-30 08:00:00 - 2013-12-31 16:00:00`
     Price      
 Min.   :15.00  
 1st Qu.:15.00  
 Median :16.50  
 Mean   :17.67  
 3rd Qu.:19.50  
 Max.   :23.00
```

This should be way faster than using a `for()`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
# You should set timestamps as the vector of all "certain timestamps" and max.time.diff to "1.33 days"
# I assume there is a subtraction operator for posixct, which produces a number (check it!), if not, use as.double
# timestamps <- ...
# max.time.diff <- ...
len <- length(timestamps)
mins <- rep(NA, len)
maxs <- mins
means <- mins
for (i in seq(len)) {
    timestamp <- timestamps[i]
    prices <- m1$Price[abs(m1$Timestamp - timestamp) <= max.time.diff] 
    mins[i] <- min(prices)
    maxs[i] <- max(prices)
    means[i] <- mean(prices)
}
```

Comment: i have to subset for example. my timestamp is x and y timestamp must be 1.33days past. and it should iterate for every 15min

Comment: @ramakrishnajanga you wrote this already, and you should set timestamps and max.time.diff accordingly.